# $1 + \frac 64 + \frac {14}8 + \frac {30}{16} + \ldots$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I have to calculate the sum upto n terms of the following:

$$1 + \frac 64 + \frac {14}8 + \frac {30}{16} + \ldots$$

I found the general term as:

$$T_n = \frac {an^2+bn+c}{2^{n}},$$ where a, b and c are determined as follows:

$$a+b+c=2; 4a+2b+c=6; 9a+3b+c=14.$$

Solving and applying:

$$T_n = \frac {2n^2-2n+2}{2^{n}} = \frac {n^2-n+1}{2^{n-1}}.$$

Now, how to compute:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac {k^2-k+1}{2^{k-1}}$$

Comment: The general term of your series seems wrong

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The general term of the sum is wrong check for $k=4$ for example, actually the sum of the $N$ first terms is :
$$1 + \frac 64 + \frac {14}8 + \frac {30}{16} + \ldots=\sum_{k=1}^{N} \frac {2^{k+1}-2}{2^k}=\sum_{k=1}^{N} \frac {2(2^{k}-1)}{2^k}\\=\sum_{k=1}^{N} \frac {2^{k}-1}{2^{k-1}}=\sum_{k=1}^{N} 2-\sum_{k=1}^{N} \frac {1}{2^{k-1}}=2N+\left(\frac 1 2\right)^{N-1}-2$$

Comment: Should it be $2N+(\frac{1}{2})^{N-1}-2$?

Comment: @SquirtleSquad Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

How about choosing $$T_n=\frac{\frac23n^3-2n^2+\frac{16}3n-2}{2^n}$$ whose elements match the few elements you mentioned and $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}T_n=14.$$

[Here](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2322249?origin=crossref&seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) is an interesting discussion.